# Button onclick event not working in iOS unless you go away from app and back, then it works

Tags: jquery, ios, html, bootstrap-4, phonegap

CHANGING QUESTION WITH NEW INFO

Previously I asked the question below. But more details show that if you go to switch to a different app by going to unselect the app (may not be the right term) and then selecting the app, the button works. If you shut down the app and restart it doesn't work again. Very strange. I'm posting the complete page code below this paragraph, everything below that is the old question and partial code under the ------ line

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /> <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" /><meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome-all.css" />-->

        <script defer src="js/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
        <script src="framwork7/framwork7.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script><script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/poppe.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/news-feed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script>
            var xmlhttp;
            var url;

/* window.onload = function()
      {
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", init);
      }
      */
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false)

            function init(){
                document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', getData);
            }


            function getData(){
                url = "http://www.example.org/myapp.php";
                url += "?cemetery=" + document.getElementById('cemetery').value;
                url += "&lastname=" + document.getElementById('lastname').value;
                url += "&firstname=" + document.getElementById('firstname').value;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: url,
                    success: function(data){
                        document.getElementById('laloinfo').innerHTML = "";
                        document.getElementById('laloinfo').innerHTML = "<strong>Scroll down for results</strong>"; 
                        /* document.getElementById('lalo2').innerHTML = data; */
                        $("#lalo2").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <title>Catholic Cemeteries Mobile App</title>
    </head>


    <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary mb-3">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Catholic Cemeteries</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> ↓  </span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="lalo.html"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> Locate a Loved One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.org','_system');"><i class="fas fa-cloud"></i> Website</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="locations.html"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> Locations & Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://facebook.com/myfacebook','_system');"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutModal" href="#aboutModal"><i class="fas fa-question"></i> About Version</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>myname</h1>
      <p class="lead">Welcome to the my name Mobile App</p>

  <div class="row">

    <!-- LALO -->
    <div class="card bg-light" id="lalo">

        <div class="card-header"><h3><i class="far fa-heart"></i> Locate a Loved One</h3></div>

        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="text-justify">Catholic Cemeteries is proud to announce our new <strong>Locate a Loved One</strong> search engine. Enter your loved one's name to get location information such as crypts / niches, section, row, and grave number.</div>
    <br>
        <div class="text-justify"><strong>You must choose a cemetery and at least a partial last name to search the database.</strong></div>
    <br>
        <div class="text-justify bg-info"><i>Please Note: Please allow approximately one week for current activity to appear in this search engine. If you can not find your loved one, please call the appropriate cemetery for assistance.</i></div>
        <br>

                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <label for="cemetery">Cemetery: Required</label>
                    <select id="cemetery" class="form-control-sm">
                        <option value="1">J Cemetery, Middle Village</option>
                        <option value="3">C Cemetery, Farmingdale</option>
                        <option value="4">M Cemetery, Flushing</option>
                        <option value="2">H Cemetery, Brooklyn</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <label for="lastname">Last Name: Required - Parital OK</label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="50" id="lastname" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Enter Last name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="30" id="firstname" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Enter First name">
                </div>
<input type="hidden" name="timecounter" value="Submit">
            <br><button class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" value="Search" id="Submit">~SEARCH~</button><br/>         
        </div>
</div>
    <!-- LALO -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- MODAL -->
   <div class="modal" id="aboutModal">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title">My Name Mobile App</h5>
           <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           Mobile App version 2.0.9<br/>
           <br/>
           If you are having an issue with this app, please contact me and give them the version number above.
         </div>
           <hr/>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
<footer><p class="text-center">copyright &copy; 2018, me</p></footer>




</body>
</html>
```

-----------------------------OLD QUESTION BELOW------------------------------

I've tried 10 solutions that I've found and none work. I have a form that can't just submit because it receives back data to then put into a div. This code is working for android, but not iOS. (This is an HTML 5 app using framework7 and bootstrap, then built with phonegap). It is a search form that submits to a server php page and takes the results back and puts them into a div. iOS does nothing when you click on the button.

Here is the button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" value="Search" id="Submit">~SEARCH~</button>
```

Here is the handler code:

```
  <script>
  var xmlhttp;
  var url;

  window.onload = function()
  {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
  }

  function init()
  {


    document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', getData, false );
  }

  function getData(){

    url = "http://www.mywebsite.org/myapp.php";
      url += "?cemetery=" + document.getElementById('cemetery').value;
      url += "&lastname=" + document.getElementById('lastname').value;
      url += "&firstname=" + document.getElementById('firstname').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById('laloinfo').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('laloinfo').innerHTML = "<strong>Scroll down for results</strong>";
            /* document.getElementById('lalo2').innerHTML = data; */
            $("#lalo2").html(data);

        }
    });

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help. It's driving me nuts and has been a week of torture.

John

Comment: Do you see an error in the Safari console?  You can use Safari on a Mac and debug the Javascript running on a device or simulator.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the input. It actually runs fine on a mac/safari using the phonegap server on the network to test. But it is not a device/simulator. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var xmlhttp;
      var url;

      $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#Submit').on('click', getData);
      }); 


      function getData(){

        url = "http://www.mywebsite.org/myapp.php";
          url += "?cemetery=" + $('#cemetery').val();
          url += "&lastname=" + $('#lastname').val();
          url += "&firstname=" + $('#firstname').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
               $('#laloinfo').html= "";
                $('#laloinfo').html= "<strong>Scroll down for results</strong>";
                /* $('#lalo2').html= data; */
                $("#lalo2").html(data);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Amine, I just tried this in safari and it doesn't work. The old code worked in safari, but not on the iphone, but your code doesn't even work in safari. Unlesss I typed something wrong which I will check but I don't think so.

Comment: add the jquery.js to your page and it will work and activate the scripts from the browser it may be desactivated

Comment: jquery is loaded, not sure what you mean by activate the scripts from browser.

Comment: 1- Click the "Safari" menu, choose "Preferences"
2- Click on the "Security" tab
3- Click the "Enable JavaScript" checkbox to enable or disable JavaScript
4- Close the "Preferences" window
5- JavaScript is now enabled

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video demonstrating how to debug an iOS WebView directly.

https://youtu.be/gZUj4KfFpQ4

This should make it easy to see where you're going wrong.

To create and open a Cordova app in Xcode for debugging:

```
[ ~] cordova create TestApp com.mydomain.testapp "TestApp"
Creating a new cordova project.
[ ~] cd TestApp/
[ ~/TestApp] cordova platform add ios --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.4
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: com.mydomain.testapp
    Name: TestApp
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.4
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" to config.xml
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving ios@~4.5.4 into config.xml file ...

[ ~/TestApp] open platforms/ios/TestApp.xcworkspace
[ ~/TestApp]
```

At this point in Xcode just choose your simulator and click the Run triangle:

[image]

The steps are:

1. On the Mac in Safari, go to **Preferences... -> Advanced** and enable **Show Develop menu in the menu bar**
2. Ensure the app is running on the simulator
3. In Safari choose **Develop -> Simulator -- iPhone (model) -> choose the WebView** -- note the WebView will highlight as you mouse over it in the menu
4. Begin Javascript debugging

Comment: This gets even stranger. So I used the phonegap server to test on safari from the ma, then from safari in the simulator (I can't figure out how to get the actual app into the simulator) and it works fine. Then I had someone test it on their iphone again in testflight, didn't work, then all of a sudden it worked, then stopped working. I'm wondering if it's the page not completing the load. It seems like it is, but maybe it's not. And so maybe the listener on window.onload isn't functioning properly.

Comment: Updated with details on debugging a Cordova/Phonegap app in Xcode.  That's the only way you're going to find the issue.

Comment: Thank you again, I will look at this tomorrow when I get in. However one more clue. I just got from my testers that when you go into the app, it doesn't work. If you close the app and go back in, it doesn't work. BUT, if you leave the app (it is still running technically, but changing focus away from the app) then go to the running apps, choose that app, it then works. So defocusing the app, then focusing the app makes it work.

Comment: It is working in the simulator so that's not showing issues. But on the phones when you go into the page and hit search nothing happens, but if you keep the app running and go to another app, then back, the search works.